# How can I select only one line from foreach array

Tags: php

I just need to display one line from fruits.

```
$fruits = 'Apple, Banana, Lemon, Strawberry';
$rows = explode(', ' ,$fruits);
foreach($rows as $row => $data){
      $row_data = explode('^', $data);
      $info[$row]['id']= $row_data[0];

    Apple
    Banana
    Lemon
    Strawberry
```

Comment: So what is your question? If you want to display, then do that. Why is that a problem? What is your _real_ question?

Comment: I just want the result just a banana

Comment: Well, that would be `$rows[2]`... Apart from that: what should that _second_ `explode()` do?

Answer (score 1):

From your code, `foreach($rows as $row => $data)`, `$row` stores the index of each array element and `$data` contains its data. If you want to pick using index, you can try looking the data in as `$rows[0]` or `$rows[1]` and so on. In your code above, you don't really need a foreach, you can grab the results as shown below

```php
$fruits = 'Apple, Banana, Lemon, Strawberry';
$rows = explode(', ' ,$fruits);

echo($rows[0]); // outputs Apple
echo($rows[1); // outputs Banana
echo($rows[2]); // outputs Lemon
echo($rows[3]); // outputs Strawberry
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$row_data = explode('^', $data);` doesn't appear to be doing what you think it will. Try something like this:

```
$info = [];
$fruits = explode(', ' ,'Apple, Banana, Lemon, Strawberry');
foreach($fruits as $index => $fruit){
  $info[$index]['id'] = $fruit;
}
```

or even:

```
$info = [];
$fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon', 'Strawberry'];
foreach($fruits as $index => $fruit){
  $info[$index]['id'] = $fruit;
}
```